# Is it possible to implement an activation function or layer in Keras that uses two distinct sets of weights?

Tags: python, keras

Is it possible to define a function or layer such that there exist two sets of weights and biases? For instance, where a normal sigmoidal activation function is `1/(1+e^-x)`, is it possible to have some layer where the activation function would be e.g. `1/(1+y*e^-x)` with y being the result of the second input weights and bias.

Comment: Do you mean both `x` and `y` are **inputs** to this activation layer? If so, yes it's possible. It's also possible that `y` to be a trainable weight and that could be implemented in Keras as well. Which one is your intention?

Comment: My intention is that rather than having a neuron activation f(x), the activation is instead f(x,y). As with any other neuron, `x` is the sum of weights multiplied by inputs and the bias; `y` is the same--but `x` and `y` should not share the same weights or inputs.

Comment: All right, that's possible and fairly easy to implement. However, let me correct you: the constraints you mentioned such as "x is the sum of weights multiplied by inputs and the bias; y is the same" or "x and y should not share the same weights or inputs" could not be enforced or checked by a layer. Instead, these things are determined based on the architecture of your model and the type of layers you are using. For example, in my own task I may decide to use `f(x,x)` instead (i.e. both inputs are the same). You see? I am using the same layer differently. All that matter is the logic of layer.

Comment: Your custom layer could be described as this: it takes two input tensors `x` and `y` of the same shape, and return `1 / (1+y * e^(-x))` as output. That's all we need to know to implement this layer. After implementing it, this is in the hand of the user and their specific use case which determine how this layer could be used.

Comment: What if the tensors are different shapes? For instance, `x` is an entire input data set, and `y` is the output of a separate processing stream; or `x` looks at the centre of an image but `y` the edges.

Comment: Their shapes should be such that the element-wise multiplication (i.e. `y * e^(-x)`) could be done. If one of the tensors could be [broadcasted](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/broadcasting) to have the same shape as the other one, then it's also fine.

Comment: Ah, I see where I've been confusing. I don't mean that anything happens on a per element basis. More specifically, what I'm trying is `i = Σx*w+b` and `j = Σy*v+c`, whilst the activation function is then `1/(1+j*e^(-i))`.

Comment: So? What difference does this make? Again, if you want to implement an activation function, just think about its logic and not about how its inputs were formed or computed. I can apply sigmoid activation on the output of a LSTM layer and also it's completely valid to apply it on the output of a convolution layer (or any other layer). So the inputs are not important; the important part is the logic of activation function itself.

Comment: The difference it makes is whether the inputs can be arranged to correctly function. My use case for this activation is most similar to a standard dense layer, but the output of a dense layer is calculated in such a way that the input cannot be split into the two classes required and the supplied activation operates on a single scalar value. My question is whether it is feasible to have a layer that takes two inputs and produces two scalar values before its activation, or if it would be possible to have some construct of multiple layers that breaks this process down.

Comment: Let's discuss on a real implementation; otherwise we'll get nowhere. Please see my answer and provide your comments there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layer (or activation function) you described could be easily implemented. It takes two input tensors, `x` and `y`, which have compatible shapes and return as output `1 / (1 + y * e^(-x))`. So using the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers) as our guide, we can implement it like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MultSigmoid(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MultSigmoid, self).__init__()

    def call(self, inputs):
        x, y = inputs
        return 1.0 / (1.0 + y * tf.math.exp(-x))
```

And now, just for demonstration, we can use it like this:

```
inp1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,))
inp2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(5,))

d1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(6)(inp1)
d2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(6)(inp2)

out = MultSigmoid()([d1, d2])
```

Note that in our implementation we assumed that `y * e^(-x)` is the element-wise multiplication. If instead, we are interested in tensor (or matrix) multiplication, we can use [`tf.matmul`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matmul) like: `tf.matmul(y, tf.math.exp(-x))`; however, note that in both cases it's assumed that the shapes are compatible with each other and the multiplication could be done, otherwise an error is raised.

Comment: That worked for getting me started with what I need to do, but I think I should point out one error: `def MultSigmoid(tf.keras.layers.Layer):` should be `class MultiSigmoid(tf.keras.layers.Layer)`. At least, it was just a source of errors until that got fixed.

Comment: @Rain Oh, so sorry. Fixed it. Thanks for mentioning it.